# Marketo submit only non empty fields

Tags: marketo

Is there any way to send only filled fields and ignore empty ones? I'm trying to use `form.setValues(nonEmtyValues)`, but it doesn't work

Like this:

```
MktoForms2.loadForm("//app-sjst.marketo.com", "785-UHP-775", 1057, function(form){
        var obj = form.vals();
        for (var propName in obj) {
            if (obj[propName] === null || obj[propName] === '') {
                delete obj[propName]
            }
        }
        form.setValues(obj)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be overthinking this when it comes to Marketo and blank fields. By default, if you successfully submit a form to Marketo, it won't nullify blank fields.

If you had a form where you had someone fill out only Last Name with no First Name value, but the database already has an existing value for First Name, it won't be overwritten—it just stays as the same value.